# how to use typescript to set unique property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-types

I have some data in my code like below:

```
interface Product {
    id: number
    name: string;
}

enum EnumValue {
  'VALUE1' = 'VALUE1',
  'VALUE2' = 'VALUE2',
  'VALUE3' = 'VALUE3',
}

const data = {
  'VALUE1': {
    num1: {id: 1, name: '2'},
    num2: {id: 2, name: '2'},
  },
    'VALUE2': {
    num1: {id: 1, name: '2'},
  },
    'VALUE3': {
    num1: {id: 1, name: '2'},
  },
} as const satisfies { readonly [key in EnumValue]: { [key: string]: Product} };
```

I need to Define a validator for my data type so it only takes unique ids for each `EnumValue` property. I mean

```
data = {
 'VALUE1': {
    num1: {id: 1, name: '2'},
    num2: {id: 1, name: '2'},
  },
    'VALUE2': {
    num1: {id: 1, name: '2'},
  },
    'VALUE3': {
    num1: {id: 1, name: '2'},
  },
}
```

ts should throw error because VALUE1 has 2 objects with  id = 1 but

```
data = {
 'VALUE1': {
    num1: {id: 1, name: '2'},
    num2: {id: 2, name: '2'},
  },
    'VALUE2': {
    num1: {id: 1, name: '2'},
  },
    'VALUE3': {
    num1: {id: 1, name: '2'},
  },
```

is a valid value.
i need `as const satisfies` part to use data model type in my code.
so can you help me define a validator to correct my data type?

There is some code to validate unique ids over an array of objects that may help but the problem is i don't know how to access object values to iterate on in type validation. [link to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69688023/typescript-object-set-with-unique-property?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
interface IProduct<Id extends number> {
    id: Id
    name: string;
}

type Validation<
    Products extends IProduct<number>[],
    Accumulator extends IProduct<number>[] = []>
    =
    (Products extends []
        // #1 Last call
        ? Accumulator
        // #2 All calls but last
        : (Products extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
            ? (Head extends IProduct<number>
                // #3 Check whether [id] property already exists in our accumulator 
                ? (Head['id'] extends Accumulator[number]['id']
                    ? (Tail extends IProduct<number>[]
                        // #4 [id] property is a duplicate, hence we need to replace it with [never] in order to trigger the error
                        ? Validation<Tail, [...Accumulator, { id: never, name: Head['name'] }]>
                        : 1)
                    // #5 [id] is not a duplicate, hence we can add to our accumulator whole product
                    : (Tail extends IProduct<number>[]
                        ? Validation<Tail, [...Accumulator, Head]>
                        : 2)
                )
                : 3)
            : Products)
    )
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPJzkN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes it solved my problem. Thank you for your solution and Yes it could be nice if you explain the approach too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific type `ValidData` in TypeScript corresponding to your requirement that each property have unique `id` subproperties, so you can't write `const data = {⋯} as const satisfies ValidData`. Instead you can make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `ValidData<T>` type that checks the input type `T` and validates it, along with a helper `validData()` function. So you'd write `const data = validData({⋯});` and it would either succeed or fail based on the input.

---

First lets write a `BasicData<K>` type to represent a supertype of all `ValidData<T>` types, where we don't care about the uniqueness of the `id`; all we care about is that it has keys `K` and values whose properties are all `Product`s:

```
type BasicData<K extends PropertyKey = EnumValue> =
  Record<K, { [k: string]: Product }>;
```

Note that I've used a [default generic type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that `BasicData` by itself corresponds to `BasicData<EnumValue>`, which is basically the same as what you were using after `satisfies`.

Then, `ValidData<T>` would look like

```
type ValidData<T extends BasicData<keyof T>> =
  { [K in keyof T]: UniqueId<T[K]> }
```

where `UniqueId<T>` is a validator generic that makes sure `T` has unique `id` properties.  Here's one way to write that:

```
type UniqueId<T extends Record<keyof T, Product>> =
  { [K in keyof T]: {
    id: Exclude<T[K]["id"], T[Exclude<keyof T, K>]["id"]>,
    name: string
  } }
```

This is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `T` where each property is a `Product` whose `id` property explicitly [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers)s the `id` properties from all other keys.  `T[Exclude<keyof T, K>]` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all properties of `T` except the one with key `K`.  And so that `id` property looks like "Take the `id` property of this property and `Exclude` the `id` properties from all other properties."

If the `id` properties are unique, this will end up not excluding anything. If they are not, then the `id` property for the duplicates will end up being [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  So if `UniqueId<T>` extends `T`, then `T` is valid. Otherwise, `T` is invalid in exactly those properties with duplicate `id`s.

So now we can write `validData()` like this:

```
const validData =
  <const T extends BasicData & BasicData<keyof T> & ValidData<T>>(
    d: T) => d;
```

This uses a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) so that callers don't need to remember to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).  The [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all the individual constraints we care about.  The first is `BasicData`, meaning it must have all the keys of `EnumValue`. The second is `BasicData<keyof T>`, meaning for each property it does have, all of the properties must be a bag of `Product`s.  And the final one is `ValidData<T>`, meaning that its properties must have unique `id`s.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
const data = validData({
  'VALUE1': {
    num1: { id: 1, name: '2' },
    num2: { id: 2, name: '2' },
  },
  'VALUE2': {
    num1: { id: 1, name: '2' },
  },
  'VALUE3': {
    num1: { id: 1, name: '2' },
  },
}); // okay

const data2 = validData({
  'VALUE1': {
    num1: { id: 1, name: '2' }, // error
    num2: { id: 1, name: '2' }, // error
  },
  'VALUE2': {
    num1: { id: 1, name: '2' },
  },
  'VALUE3': {
    num1: { id: 1, name: '2' },
  },
});
```

Looks good. For `data1` everything passes. For `data2`, the `'VALUE1'` property fails, and the `id` properties for both `num1` and `num2` have errors saying that they are not assignable to `never`.  It's not the prettiest error message, but it works.

You could do some complicated mess to try to make the error message more understandable:

```
type Repl<T, U> = [T] extends [never] ? U : T;

// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689 workaround
interface ErrMsg<T> { nope: never, msg: T } 

type UniqueId<T extends Record<keyof T, Product>> =
  { [K in keyof T]: {
    id: Repl<Exclude<T[K]["id"], T[Exclude<keyof T, K>]["id"]>,
      ErrMsg<`conflicts with ${string &
        { [P in keyof T]:
          T[K]["id"] & T[P]["id"] extends never ? never : Exclude<P, K>
        }[keyof T]}`>>,
    name: string
  } }


const data2 = validData({
  'VALUE1': {
    num1: { id: 1, name: '2' }, // ErrMsg<"conflicts with num2">
    num2: { id: 1, name: '2' }, // ErrMsg<"conflicts with num1">
  },
  'VALUE2': {
    num1: { id: 1, name: '2' },
  },
  'VALUE3': {
    num1: { id: 1, name: '2' },
  },
});
```

But I consider that out of scope for this question and I won't digress further by explaining it here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCzIDeAUMssFgFzIg4C2ARtKTXHRNQM5hSgDmAbmIBfYsQi06yAKKSAanAA2OFCTIByOQEEAMgFVpARnXIAvMk26DxgDQtL+6QCYT5hwZd2N2xwGZXFj4G-naixGAAngAOKABCcJzACAAicGBwADwA0sgQAB6QIFicaJgxUJFZEBFmMvJKKgB8ZiwAShAIGFBY2TZEyADaANZcPPwAutTo2HgEwo1C4dEoCooUqekZACq5BRLFyPGJKWmZQ9UYMMhbjc2mLISDOaDI5xGX15PIeiDAAI4qACSPS2Ayy42aYUiMW+vwBEGB212hQO7U63Qybw+Wz601w+FuLTIjzB5BArwuVy2XzUZHIVBkeQQyiwEG2YPGAwARBQueM+qDpEyWWysVS+llGpyeVg+Y0WGQQGwOMhuLwQHwWMJkGFiJ0QNxkAA3JTrU5E5AZfWGnb5FElI5JDZwZAAMkOCSdp0xlOuzXdqzNmxujQAFArkAytgBKMzNLCLa0ELDm8wmtZYZ2h2nuIzqai0xX0QwF+nUQx9JXsajqFw6rx0yROUsUahOSvKmt14QNnv2ILOfNECOSEv9VvICusasWbu9hu5-wFkfFlsMqdVlW1kx9sh94TRxMYA3J05OWrpoNwbP9qx55d0mir8frjsz7f15AAei-uSgmCgFc6GbF9yzfLc52-X9oAArUFwHFwH0bZ9HgnDdO1nHd51vPwh0LJ86DHVDX2nCCsLgkRDzETdOCiRAUAAYQwOgojWBA0ggLAAFkIE4EoSDEFhoRWU1M29W09iKB1PROTYxT9O4IxJZ5yXk6lqB+f4gRBDlITEMhhOQdpWO2Po9DuQZqWRfYSgGEAICNaBxmQAB+b5kGoLYhDIUBIFgeiZH-LjOD4bZmkeEAMBiah7McqA+joELPJ1ITllhLSERBaypKMjouh6NTcUwfEwEJe5H2UskKXeKkaQjHyGWMxQMiFZkcFZdlwW5Xl+WuAZWpFH0auuCUpW62UIQbR8yGkIKQoyAADfUYDYsASgAd2AMAAAtkAAEkINV+DderppJVAqrUyZTumvquplPk3T61BpR67KDli6BXJoByvuoAb2rZVBRpuulhGGX1qWEBbbimxsMKOjUI21MIyCTY1ROdC0yCtY8bXe6Tjix91HVks5If9ZBAzE4NbnDW6o1jUx40WNG8dPdIL0x04b0fXNjCQx9RzXMDSK7cjbqbEXkHbMXMPrZG4dzRDh0llCy0ncDxYVx9dzpRc8NO4XQM1uWPz1vdeyolh0ZTdJzzTbn0l5-WBwF1XpuN4jRc3bWeygwKoGC0KuWW1aNq23amy5eU1eA6X0PfSCf0D4OMlD48VqSNbkE2naCMMGPFYjZXDbjoiNcTsidbBpWByXD2hfVtCtfli2a4PIRhCAA)